# awk range pattern - do something at range pattern beginning

Tags: awk, gawk

I need to know, which line was the line matched with range pattern with awk.
Suppose I have following input:

```
some random text
some random text START this is first line I want to match with START
some random text
some random text
some random text
some random text START this line contains another START but I dont want matched this line
some random text
some random text END this line is last of my range
some random text
... input text countinues, more range matches can be found
```

How I wanted to match:

```
/START/,/END/ {
if ((index($0,"START"))) {
# do something when range starts
}
#do some other things
}
```

But then I realized, that my index would match START at line 6 in the middle of range. Im thinking about raising a flag after first match of START with index, but is there some more elegant way like global variable similar to NR?

EDIT: input text continues, more range matches can be found, if I raised flag or used counting, I would have to reset flag/count after range ends (add index($0,"END")), what I dont want

Answer (score 0):

You could read everything first into an array and then operate on its first element only. I'm not sure if it could be made prettier than a marker flag though.

Answer (score 0):

One way. Try incrementing a variable inside the range, only when it is equal to 1 matches the beginning of the range. In second `START` line it will be 5 and won't succeed the check `i == 1`.

```
/START/,/END/ {
    ++i 
    if ( i == 1 ) { 
        print "Range starts"
    }   
    print "Other things"
}
```